# Twitter bootstrap carousel with many active items

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel. I've implemented the one that is on their website, but I need a little customization:

- Instead of displaying 1 picture at a time, I want to show 4
- The left arrow should be in the left of the first image
- The right arrow should be right to the last image

Is there any way to do this?

This is what i've tryed until now:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <section class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><img src="img/slide1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/slide2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/slide3.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/slide4.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/slide5.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/slide6.jpg"></div>
    </section>

    <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? From the [**Help Center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: So my example, is the current slider with one image displayed and 2 arrows. I need 4 images on 1 line, and the other images will come from right to left when we press on the right arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example: https://codeply.com/p/7t07Bh577D

Basically you need to put an entire `row` of images in the `item active`.

Comment: +1, great answer, although it probably shouldn't do [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/1tDt8f1.png) when the screen gets narrow.

Comment: Switching the cols to the non-stacking `xs` grid will fix that: http://bootply.com/92514 (But then the images get really tiny!)

Comment: I've noticed that on smaller devices if i want to reduce the number of items displayed, i have problems. For example on LG (4 items), MD (3 items), SM (2 items), XS (1 item). Any solution for that ?

Comment: U have example how I can do it in loop ? i struggling with the active item when its in loop